# Who is this guy in Akatsuki - naruto Shippuden Ep 455?

Tags: naruto

Who is this guy in below image?

[image]

It cannot be kakuzu or Sasori since they are in the below picture, BTW this is Episode 455 in Naruto Shippuden

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJO21.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s [Jūzō Biwa](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/J%C5%ABz%C5%8D_Biwa), a former Akatsuki member and ninja swordsman of the mist.

Very little is known about Jūzō. He is only referenced in the manga and what we do see of him in the anime is filler

Comment: Personally I don't remember seeing him (as I skipped most of fillers) but I do realized afterwards that the massive sword that Zabuza used was not his but this guy.

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami I mostly skipped the filler content as well. I only know of him through answering other questions here hahaha